# No Android sdk found (nothing to do)

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

for some reason, when installing an android studio, I did not have an android SDK installed, but I cannot install it [image: missing SDK]

[image]

by the way, I can't tick the box(the location I tried to change )

Comment: change the location of your sdk

Comment: I fixed the images. You can follow the same format for including images in the future

Comment: I tried to run as administrator, but I still can't tick the box

Comment: and I changed the location

Comment: Was the Android Studio installed in an unusual way? e.g., another user account installed it, so the paths may be writable only by that account?

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom of your second picture, it was written that: "This Path is not writable. Please choose a new location".
I recommend either use a new path or run Android-Studio as **administrator** Privilege.

Comment: I tried to run as administrator, but I still can't tick the box

Comment: and I changed the location

Answer (score 1):

As your second image shows, the path is not writable. You can run Android Studio as admin, and the path may be writable. Or select another path.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to follow:**

1. Right click on android studio icon and do Run as administrator.
2. Try to copy your folder of android-sdk into some other location.